# TextInputLayout - Change floating label hint color in EditText in rest state

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I'm using TextInputLayout with floating label hints. But In the normal state I am unable to change the hint color from white to other color. Is there a way to do this ?

```html
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/fullNameTextLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.75">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etFullName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:hint="Full Name"
        android:textColor="@color/gray_dark"
        android:textColorHint="@color/green"
        android:textColorHighlight="@color/green" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Attaching two screen shots with the background changed.

[image: Same view with green background]

[image: Same view with white background]

Comment: It is too late now probably, but I was able to just add android:textColorHint to the TextInputLayout

Answer (score 7):

Please add this in TextInputLayout,

```
  app:hintTextAppearance="@style/mytext
```

So your layout will be like :

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/aeal_input_layout_zipcode"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@color/green"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/mytext">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/aeal_etZipCode"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Zipcode"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

style.xml:

```
 <style name="mytext" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/green</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/green</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/green</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

Edited : You need to add textColorHint in TextInputLayout, and it will work properly as you needed.

It worked for me, so might help you too.

Comment: I tried this. But still they appear white. I should mention that I'm making all the edit texts focusable false initially from code. So in the above picture they are not active. I want them to show with green color even in inactive state. Is it possible?

Comment: Ya i also checked with focusable false and was not able to get what was needed. And I tried to solve the same issue and got solution for the same , so pl check my edited answer

Answer (score 2):

Got the same probleme and solved this with the setHintTextAppearance(int) method of TextInputLayout.

Example:

First find your TextInputLayout

```
android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout textInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.textInputLayout);
```

now do the following:

```
textInputLayout.setHintTextAppearance(R.style.Inactive);
```

in your styles.xml file you create your styles with the color for the hint color. For example

```
<style name="Inactive" parent="AppThemeLight">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
</style>

<style name="Active" parent="AppThemeLight">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

now, when you change things for example onButtonClick, you simply change your style.

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
textInputLayout.setHintTextAppearance(R.style.Active);
             }
         });
```

Keep in mind, that you also have to handle the Colors for your EditText inside your TextInputLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to change the hint color. -

```
editText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.xyz));
```

Solution for your problem -

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3){
        //do something
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        //do something
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        if(arg0.toString().length() <= 0) //check if length is equal to zero
            editText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.xyz));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Style.xml you can change the color of hint

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorAccent">#3498db</item>
</style>
```

For more see [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-login-screen-using-textinputlayout--cms-24168)

Answer (score 0):

try this

`<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
 ........
 android:textColorHint="requiredColor"
 ....>` to change the floating hint color and

`<EditText
android:textColor="requiredColor"` to change the hint color in edittxt